# Ignoring a field mongodb request

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb

Let's say we have objects like this in a mongodb collection:

```
{
  _id: 00000001
  colors: ["green", "yellow"],
  houses: [
    {
      number: 1,
      owner: "John"
    },
    {
      number: 2,
      owner: "John"
    },
    {
      number:3,
      owner: "Dave"
    }
  ]
},
{
  _id: 00000002
  colors: ["green", "red"],
  houses: [
    {
      number: 15,
      owner: "Dave"
    },
  ]
}
```

So, to get every object where the color array contains the color green the query I would need to write would look smth like this: `collection.find({colors: "green"});`
Now if I would like to get all the objects in which John owns a house, how would I formulate such a query? 
Basically what I am asking is, if my query would be `collection.find({houses: {owner: "John", number: ?}})` what would I need to replace the `"?"` with to tell mongo that I don't care what value number has. 
Or maybe there is another approach that I haven't thought of?
Thank you for any help!
(Btw this is a made up example hence why the IDs look weird and the object in itself doesn't seem very useful.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To query an array of objects you can use the [dot notation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-array-of-documents/#specify-a-query-condition-on-a-field-embedded-in-an-array-of-documents), try:

```
db.collection.find({ "houses.owner": "John"}})
```

Comment: That did work indeed, thank you very much, exactly what I was looking for :)